# Spring Data Mongodb find by starts with

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I'm using Spring data with mongodb.
I have a collection called place :

```
{ 
  "_id" : NumberLong(281469), 
  "_class" : "com.domain.Place", 
  "name" : "paris"
}
```

I want to get places starting with some String. 
In mongo console I could get the result using :

```
db.place.find({name : {$regex : /^par/, $options: 'i'}})
```

Using the spring data repositories I've tried this but always give an empty result:

```
@Query(value="{'name' : {$regex : ?0, $options: 'i'}}")
public Page<PlaceDetails> findByNameStartsWith(String name,Pageable pageable);
```

And in the call of the repository method, I make a concatenation this way :

```
repository.findByNameStartsWith("/^"+token+"/",new PageRequest(0,10));
```

while this repository method works :

```
@Query(value="{'name' : ?0}")
public Page<PlaceDetails> findByName(String name,Pageable pageable);
```

The class is declared this way :

```
@Document(collection="place")
public class PlaceDetails {
//...
}
```

Any idea why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`StartsWith` automatically applies the necessary wrapping into a regex, so with your client code you effectively wrap it twice. If you think about it: with your approach, the client effectively has to know that the starts-with clause is implement with a regex, which would be leaking internals.

So a simple:

```
repository.findByNameStartsWith(token, new PageRequest(0,10));
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `MongoTemplate` then you can search startsWith like this ("i" is for ignore case)

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("name").regex("^" + prefix, "i"));

mongoTemplate.find(query, PlaceDetails.class);
```

EndsWith are like:

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("name").regex(suffix + "$", "i"));

mongoTemplate.find(query, PlaceDetails.class);
```